# Forward, rewind audio using AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios6, streaming, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer for playing streamed audio file. I want to implement fast forward, rewind options for audio player. How to achieve these features using AVPlayer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006757/unable-to-implement-forward-action-in-avaudioplayer

Answer (score -1):

There appear to be a bunch of discussions and guides out there you can draw material from for this particular request.

Here's some questions on StackOverflow itself which deal with the same functions for AVPlayer. Check them out, and any linked info they lead to.

- [Fast Rewind & Fast Forward in AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478472/fast-rewind-fast-forward-in-avaudioplayer)
- [How to perform operations when playing sound in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558288/how-to-perform-operations-when-playing-sound-in-iphone)
- [Unable to Implement Forward Action in AVAudioplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006757/unable-to-implement-forward-action-in-avaudioplayer)

Comment: I don't want to use AVAudioPlayer as it doesn't support streaming. I am streaming audio with AVPlayer.

Comment: This question is about `AVPlayer` as @darshana has mentioned. This is not an answer to this question.